# Difference between criterion validity and reliability equivalence

Tags: methodology, experiment-design

In the book [*Doing research in the real world*](http://www.sagepub.com/booksProdDesc.nav?prodId=Book239646) by David E. Gray, there is a section on experiment design. When discussing validity and reliability, the author defines “criterion validity” as

> This is where we compare how people have answered a new measure of a concept, with existing, widely accepted measures of a concept.

and a little later, in the “Reliability” part, there is a subheading “Equivalence”, which says

> Another way of testing the reliability of an instrument is by comparing the
>   responses of a set of subjects with responses made by the same set of subjects on another instrument (preferably on the same day).

So if I got this right, we are both times measuring if there is a difference between the answer on our new instrument and another, existing instrument.

Is there a practical difference between the two concepts, or only a philosophical one? And whether practical or philosophical, what *is* the actual difference?

**Update** The author discusses validity and reliability in general, then lists 7 different aspects of validity and 5 different aspects of reliability. "Criterion validity" and "reliability equivalence" are only one type of each, respectively. Please consider in your answer that this question is not about validity vs. reliability in general, but only about these two specific aspects.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about experiment design and not academia.

Comment: The list of topics doesn't say that research methodology is off-topic, and doing proper research is part of being in academia. Is there an existing policy against "how is research done" questions, and where can I read about it? I don't personally see a good argument why being a good university teacher should be on topic but being a good university researcher should be off topic.

Comment: @StrongBad is there any SE website where you would see this question fit better than AC.SE? Just curious. Cross Validated does not seem to be the place (in case).

Comment: CV is the right place, because validity and reliability play a big role in measurement and research design, thus deserve focus in statistics and epidemiology (what CV focuses on.)

Comment: Cross validated is absolutely *not* the right place. Statistical validity is a tiny part of validity. This is about theory of science, not about statistics.

Comment: Anyhow, I often feel we spend too much time putting questions into silo. Answer submitted.

Comment: @dgraziotin not that I know of, otherwise I would have suggested it :)

Comment: Let's say it's *criterion-valid* to post the question here. But I bet the answers we got here and in CV will be *reliable*.

Comment: @rumtscho sorry to have been terse. I am not sure if we have discussed if "how is research done" type questions are on topic. My feeling is that experiment design is much broader than experiment design for academics. But I only have one vote. This is probably worth a meta discussion.

Comment: To anybody interested, I posted a question on meta, http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/779/are-questions-on-the-theory-of-academic-research-on-topic

Comment: @StrongBad the fact that experiments are also used outside of science shouldn't be a reason to not accept the question here. Alcohol is used outside of human consumption, as a biofuel for example, and corn starch is used to make plastics. On Cooking.SE, we still answer questions about alcohol and corn starch, unless they happen to be obviously focused on the non-cooking application only.

Comment: I disagree that CV is the wrong place, but I +1'd your point that statistical validity isn't the whole story anyway. Thing is, same's true of CV answers. Lots of good scientists over there with a strong sense of validity in a larger sense and plenty of enthusiasm for extending it beyond statistical issues alone (e.g., [Is Facebook coming to an end?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/83136/32036)). That being said, no objection from me to asking here; +1!

Comment: @NickStauner the validity of a research tool is not a statistical topic, it is a topic from scientific theory. We happen to use statistic methods as a convenient way to measure it. Many statisticians will know quite a bit about it, because statistics is applied on data coming from experiments, and therefore statisticians learn about good experiments. It is sad that many grad students are not taught scientific theory and research methodology separately and only have some exposure during other courses, for example statistics - but it is a separate research field.

Comment: No disagreement if you're saying there are meaningful differences (nor with the deplorability of grad education on basic theory and methodology, or your comment in general), but as a statistician might say, `validity` and `statistics` are only partially independent :) I only really disagree that CV is a bad place to ask! I acknowledge that meta-SO discourages cross-posting, but [I've managed to do it successfully myself](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/11283/6389) following [some advice on how to pull it off justifiably](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75012/246931). Worth considering no?

Comment: @NickStauner and anybody else bothered by my insistence that this one question is for here, please see my post at http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/784/103. I made a mistake in hastily wording that comment in such a provocative way, but did not mean to imply that Crossvalidating is in general a bad place for asking on validity and reliability.

Answer (score 7):

**Criterion validity** concerns with *measuring the right thing*. For instance, GPA is likely to have criterion validity to measure a student's academic understanding. While the change in weight in the last semester has much less criterion validity to measure the same trait. Basically, if the measurement you use and the trait you want to measure has a high correlation, then there is likely criterion validity.

**Reliability** concerns mostly with *measuring the thing right*. For instance, if GPA can measure a student's academic understanding, and percent attendance can also measure a student's academic understanding, then GPA and percent attendance should correlate, aka, they are reliable. Before subjected to reliability assessment, the tests are usually checked if they are criterion-valid. However, it's possible to have two tests that are highly correlated (reliable) but invalid. Such as using dietary fat intake and serum lipid to predict a college graduate's earning potential.

Notice that there a few different types of reliabilities, the one you cited is more about *alternate forms reliability,* there are also *test-retest reliability* and *inter-rater reliability*, etc.

Practically, they are not interchangeable. Validity happens between the true trait (or behavior) and the measurements. Reliability happens between two measurements (or modes/instances of measurement.)

Comment: See also [accuracy and precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision).

Answer (score 0):

`Validity` is comparing the new results with the existing literature, without doing extra experiments.

`Reliability` is comparing the new results with some extra experiments that you carry on with some other settings/devices.

*I agree with @StrongBad that this question is off-topic, but there is no SE site on research in general and I think this question is quite interesting.*

Comment: I don't know where this view comes from, but it is certainly not the one the book author had in mind. In another subchapter, he insists that external validity has to be shown through comparison with a series of new studies. As for the off-topic suggestion, please share your view on Meta, http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/779/are-questions-on-the-theory-of-academic-research-on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off-topic as the terms you ask for are more specific, but:

Unfortunately, there is some ambiguity as to what exactly is meant by different terms in this quality control/validation/method context.

E.g.

- in machine learning the "validation set" is often used to optimize parameters - as opposed to proving whether or not the model "does its job" (a shortened version of one definition of validity). The latter is measured with the "test set" (again, in my opinion, a rather ambiguous name).
- [The Handbook of validation in analytical chemistry](http://books.google.de/books?id=2iTNOip-scYC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&source=gbs_ge_summary_r#v=onepage&q&f=false) spends several pages to compare and discuss differences between several definitions given in literature and norms specific to the field of analytical chemistry. The bottom line of these definitions is that in analytical chemistry, validity is not only about measuring the right thing (as @Penguin_Knight nicely explained), but also about measuring the right thing *right*.

I'd therefore recommend that you state what you are speaking about rather than relying on these terms.